# Inverted Output with Rectuangular Function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a simple rectangular pulse function with Matplotlib. In the plot figure the values for y are inverted. In the console the values are correct.

What is the problem?

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np   
import scipy as sp   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   

class DSP(object):
   def __init__(self) :
       plt.clf()     
       scale, rect = self.my_own_rect(fs=10, T=np.pi, print_values=True)
       plt.plot(scale, rect)
       plt.show()

   def my_own_rect(self, fs, T, print_values):
       rect = np.zeros(fs)        
       scale = np.linspace(-T, T, fs, endpoint=False)
       for t in scale:   
           if(t >= -T/2 and t <= T/2):     
               rect[t] = 1  
           if(print_values==True):
               print t, rect[t] 

       return scale, rect
```

This is the console output:
t - rect[t]
-3.14159265359 - 0.0
-2.51327412287 - 0.0
-1.88495559215 - 0.0
-1.25663706144 - 1.0
-0.628318530718 - 1.0
0.0 - 1.0
0.628318530718 - 1.0
1.25663706144 - 1.0
1.88495559215 - 1.0
2.51327412287 - 0.0

Comment: The values in scale will be floating point. You pick one item out of that with `t` and use that to index `rect`. For indexing, you should only use integers or boolean vectors. And you don't need a loop: `rect[-T/2 < t < T/2] = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't index `rect` with `t`. `t` is a floating point value that varies from `-T` to `T`. It is not an index into the array `rect`.  For a quick fix, try this:

```
    for k, t in enumerate(scale):   
        if(t >= -T/2 and t <= T/2):     
            rect[k] = 1  
        if(print_values==True):
            print t, rect[k]
```

I say "quick fix" because there are more changes that could be recommended.  See, for example, the comment by @BasSwinckels about not needed a loop.